# Parser with multiple return types

Tags: parsing, haskell

I have problem with parsers that can manage multiple types, e.g., the parser for arithmetic expressions. At the moment my parser takes in input only integers:

```hs
aexpr :: Parser Int
aexpr = aterm `chainl` addOp

aterm :: Parser Int
aterm = afactor `chainl` mulOp

afactor :: Parser Int
afactor = parenP '(' aexpr ')'
          <|>
          do
            s <- sign 
            a <- aexpr 
            return (s * a)
          <|>  
          token int_const
```

This works well for two integers, but I am introducing the float type, so the parser for arithmetic expressions can have in input two `Int`, two `Float` or two mixed types of `Int` and `Float`. The result type of the parser should be `Int` or `Float` based on the inputs (i.e., `Int` if both inputs are `Int`, `Float` otherwise).

My question is: what is the best way to manage this? A simple way is to just manage all the inputs as `Float`, so integer values are converted into float values. But I don't like this solution: the end result will be always `Float`.

Should I create two different parsers, i.e., one for `Int` and one for `Float`? But the two parsers would be pretty much the same.

There is a better solution?

Comment: You can make use of an `Either Int Float` as return type, so `Parser (Either Int Float)`.

Comment: If you are returning a integer or floating point value, you've written an evaluator (which parses in order to evaluate). A parser would return a parse tree or some such. (I know it sounds like a quibble but the distinction is useful.)

Answer (score 4):

When designing DSLs, it's very common to define a new data type representing all the different shapes values can have:

```
data Value
    = I Int
    | D Double
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

You may want to implement some helper functions, like:

```
binOp :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> Value -> Value -> Parser Value
binOp f (I a) (I b) = pure (I (f a b))
binOp f (D a) (D b) = pure (D (f a b))
binOp _ _ _ = fail "oof, tried to mix Ints and Doubles"
```

Then your `mulOp` and `addOp` implementations could call `binOp (*)` and `binOp (+)` somewhere in their implementation, for example.

But I would consider another approach than using such helpers directly. I would propose introducing an intermediate representation for which parsing "always succeeds", then add a separate type-checking phase where you can throw errors about mixing ints and doubles... or do appropriate casts, or whatever your DSL wants to happen there. So:

```
data BinOp = Plus | Times deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
data Type = Int | Double deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
data DSL
    = ILit Int
    | DLit Double
    | BinOp BinOp DSL DSL
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

Then you can write things with types like

```
typeCheck :: DSL -> These [TypeError] Type -- check for mixing
unsafeEval :: DSL -> Value -- implementation uses incomplete patterns and assumes no mixing

eval :: DSL -> Either [TypeError] Value
eval t = case typeCheck t of
    That _ -> Right (unsafeEval t)
    These [] _ -> Right (unsafeEval t)
    These es _ -> Left es
    This es -> Left es
```

or whatever.